# Datatables Responsive is not Working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I'm using Datatables.net latest, with datatables and bootstrap. I suppose my question is: What does Datatables Responsive Bootstrap use to detect overflow, because it clearly isn't the parent width.

Here is my result:

[image]

It's a pretty straight forward problem. If I reduce the width of my window 1 more pixel the column will finally collapse. If I then expand it, it returns to this state. I would like to prevent overflow from the parent bootstrap panel. I've removed the bootstrap grid divs (row/col-xs-12, etc) to eliminate potitial problems, but once this is resolved (or I better understand the problem) I intend to utilize the bootstrap grid system as well.

```js
var tablaCRMEtapa;
var llenartablaCRMEtapa = function () { 
    DTOptions.ajax = { "url": "@(Url.Action("ListaCrmEtapaAjax"))", "method": "POST", "data": { "IdCliente": '@ViewBag.Id' } },
    DTOptions.language = { "url": "@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables/Spanish.js")" };
    DTOptions.aoColumns =
    [
        { "sName": "Nombre", "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false },
        { "sName": "FechaInicio", "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false },
        { "sName": "FechaFin", "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
        { "sName": "Descripcion", "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false }
    ];
    tablaCRMEtapa = $('#datatableCrmEtapa').DataTable(DTOptions);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    llenartablaCRMEtapa();
});
```

```html
<div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
        <h4 class="index-title inline">@ViewBag.Title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
        <table id="datatableCrmEtapa" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr class="parent odd" role="row">
                    <th data-priority="1">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
                    </th>
                    <th data-priority="1">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaInicio)
                    </th>
                    <th data-priority="1">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaFin)
                    </th>
                    <th data-priority="2">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, translate your question to english.

Comment: It's a pretty straight forward problem. If I reduce the width of my window 1 more pixel the column will finally collapse. If I then expand it, it returns to this state. I would like to prevent overflow from the parent bootstrap panel. I've removed the bootstrap grid divs (row/col-xs-12, etc) to eliminate potitial problems, but once this is resolved (or I better understand the problem) I intend to utilize the bootstrap grid system as well.

Comment: Please use this link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51450090/edit to correct your question.

Comment: thank you very much I'm new here, the problem is that the table does not become responsive when it is displayed on mobile

Comment: $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
                .columns.adjust()
                .responsive.recalc();
        });